# Kylin Cube build is failing at #18 Step Name: Build Cube

Tags: hadoop, kylin

I am trying to build kylin cube, but all my kylin cubes are failing at same stage:

```
 #18 Step Name: Build Cube
```

I have gone through the application logs:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1485160852580_1133/container_1485160852580_1133_01_000001 (Is a directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
```

Sometimes it is failing by the following exception also:

```
Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Call From xxxxxx/192.168.1.136 to 0.0.0.0:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
java.net.ConnectException: Call From xxxxxxxxxx/192.168.1.136 to 0.0.0.0:10020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

I am not able to find the cause of this build failure.

Can anybody have help me?

UPDATE:Now i am able to create Kylin cubes successfully.Now I am trying for automate kylin cube's rebuild for every 15 minutes for getting refreshed data from hive.My kylin cube rebuild is successful every time using kylin RestfulAPI's curl command but data is not importing from Hive into Kylin cube.I am not able to find the cause,any configurations are required to work with curl command.
I am using the following  url:

http://kylin.apache.org/docs16/howto/howto_build_cube_with_restapi.html
https://kyligence.gitbooks.io/kap-manual//en/rest/authentication.en.html

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Am i missing any  settings in kylin configurations.This is the first time installing kylin 1.6 in my single node server.

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop MRJob History Server should be started if 10020 can't be accessed

Comment: sorry for delay of reply,in my server JobHistoryServer is up and running.Even then also kylin is not able to import data from hive but rebuild is showing successful.